# C - my program prints weird stuff after reading from a file

Tags: c, string, printf, fopen

I am trying to make a program for an assignment to read ID3 tags. I don't have much code so far because I'm trying to learn how to work with the ID3 tags themselves. I made a little program which would read the first three letters and just print them back, just to see how the process of opening the file and closing it would work, etc.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char buf[4];

  if (argc == 2) {
    FILE *mp3 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    fread(buf, 3, 1, mp3);
    buf[3] = "\0";
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    fclose(mp3);
    char a = buf[0];
    char b = buf[1];
    char c = buf[2];
    printf("%x\t%x\t%x\n", a, b, c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It manages to print what is it supposed to (ID3) but then it makes some weird letters appear after the ID3 part. I added a part to print the hex values of those as well.

I am new to C and I find this very difficult to understand. Also, I don't quite understand the differences between all the different ways of making and managing a string. So I would greatly appreciate any help regarding this and how to make it better and explain to me why etc.

Comment: I think that it should be `buf[3] = '\0'`. Single quotes means character, double quotes means string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! YOu said the same thing as the guy down there. It was a silly, rookie mistake on my part. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where you assign "\0" to buf[3] is wrong. You should use single quotes:

```
buf[3] = '\0';
```

The reason is that double quotes means a string literal (which is a null terminated char array) and not a char variable.

Comment: A string in C is only an array of char variables which ends in the NULL character. Many string functions process the input string from the start and continue until they find this NULL terminator. If you fail to make sure that your string ends with NULL (like the previous case), the function will just keep sending characters to the output until it finds a NULL. This will yield unpredictable results.

Comment: It did the trick. As I thought, it was a rookie mistake I made. Anyway, thanks! I appreciate it a lot :)